# Android Studio: How to get and set single data to Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

As i'm still not very good in coding, i would like to ask how can i get data and set data to a table on Azure using Android Studio easier?

I've searched on the web with sample projects and found that most of the samples are using the ToDoItem sample. But the problem is the ToDoItem sample will retrieve and list everything for the items in a list view. Can someone make it simpler by showing how to get a single String from a table based on the ID, so i can set text on a textview?

Assume i've already set up on the azure portal and have add things to the build.gradle & manifest.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone make it simpler by showing how to get a single String from a table based on the ID, so i can set text on a textview?

You could combine A `.where()` [filter clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#filtering) and a `.select()` [field selection clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#selection) as follows:

```html
List<ToDoItem> result = mToDoTable
    .where()
    .field("id").eq("xxx")
    .select("text")
    .execute()
    .get();
```

Or you could use the `lookUp()` method for retrieving an item with a specific id field as follows:

```html
ToDoItem result = mToDoTable
    .lookUp("your-id")
    .get();
```

More details, you could follow [How to use the Azure Mobile Apps SDK for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library).